# How can I add many json strings in one JsonArray?

Tags: c++, glib, arrays, json

I want one JSonArray as the output.I want json strings to be added in that array. I am using json-glib and C++ for this. I have damn searched a lot on Google but all in vain. I want something like this:

> [ {"id": "i_am_id", "client":"i_am_C" ,"tag": [{"one": "value", "two": "value"}] } ,{} ,{} ]

"tag" is a jsonarray of strings as written. I want a jsonarray of many json like this in which there are fields like string, int, jsonarrays. Please help me with this.

Comment: Your `tag` seems like a json object, not a json array. It would be enough just `"tag": {"one": "value", "two": "value"}` without brackets.

Comment: @ALittleDiff No, tag can also contain many json strings like {"one":"value"} etc. It must have those brackets as per my requirements. May be they are jsonObject or jsonarray, I need those brackets. Please tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not using json-glib,
I couldn't test this code,
and I omitted the part to release the `builder`s,
but I hope this helps you:

```
// build an object as an element of 'tag' array.
// {"one": "value", "two": "value"}
JsonNode * objectAsElementOfTag;
{
  JsonBuilder *builder = json_builder_new ();
  json_builder_begin_object (builder);

  json_builder_set_member_name (builder, "one");
  json_builder_add_string_value (builder, "value");

  json_builder_set_member_name (builder, "two");
  json_builder_add_string_value (builder, "value");

  json_builder_end_object (builder);
  objectAsElementOfTag = json_builder_get_root (builder);
}

// build 'tag' array.
// [{"one": "value", "two": "value"}]
JsonNode * tagArray;
{
  JsonBuilder *builder = json_builder_new ();
  json_builder_begin_array (builder);

  json_builder_add_value (builder, objectAsElementOfTag);

  json_builder_end_array (builder);
  tagArray = json_builder_get_root (builder);
}

// build the first element.
// {"id": "i_am_id", "client":"i_am_C" ,"tag": [{"one": "value", "two": "value"}] }
JsonNode * firstElement;
{
  JsonBuilder *builder = json_builder_new ();
  json_builder_begin_object (builder);

  json_builder_set_member_name (builder, "id");
  json_builder_add_string_value (builder, "i_am_id");

  json_builder_set_member_name (builder, "client");
  json_builder_add_string_value (builder, "i_am_C");

  json_builder_set_member_name (builder, "tag");
  json_builder_add_value (builder, tagArray);

  json_builder_end_object (builder);
  firstElement = json_builder_get_root (builder);
}

// build the second element(an empty object).
// {}
JsonNode * secondElement;
{
  JsonBuilder *builder = json_builder_new ();
  json_builder_begin_object (builder);

  json_builder_end_object (builder);
  secondElement = json_builder_get_root (builder);
}

// build the third element(an empty object).
// {}
JsonNode * thirdElement;
{
  JsonBuilder *builder = json_builder_new ();
  json_builder_begin_object (builder);

  json_builder_end_object (builder);
  thirdElement = json_builder_get_root (builder);
}

// finally, build the root array which may be what you want.
// [ {"id": "i_am_id", "client":"i_am_C" ,"tag": [{"one": "value", "two": "value"}] } ,{} ,{} ]
JsonNode * rootArray;
{
  JsonBuilder *builder = json_builder_new ();
  json_builder_begin_array (builder);

  json_builder_add_value (builder, firstElement);
  json_builder_add_value (builder, secondElement);
  json_builder_add_value (builder, thirdElement);

  json_builder_end_array (builder);
  rootArray = json_builder_get_root (builder);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped me. Can you tell me that same thing if I am given the resultant string which we have made in this and we have to read and extract all the fields? I mean the reverse of this process. Please tell. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry missed to tag you. Please help me in the problem of reading the resultant string.

Comment: @hellodear: You can use `JsonReader` to read all the fields, for example, to read the first element in the array: `JsonReader *reader = json_reader_new (rootArray);  json_reader_read_element (reader, 0); JsonNode *firstElement = json_reader_get_value (reader); json_reader_end_element (reader); // (abbr.) `

Comment: After getting first element, how should I read the option like "tag"? I know how to read id, client but not getting how to read this 'tag'. Thanks. @ALittleDiff

Comment: I am getting the resultant string as the C++ string value. Not as the JsonNode or JsonObject. Can you show the pseudocode for this? Thanks.

Comment: @hellodear: To get `tag::one` value: `JsonReader *firstElementReader = json_reader_new (firstElement);
json_reader_read_member (firstElementReader, "tag");
json_reader_read_element (firstElementReader, 0);
JsonNode *elementOfTag = json_reader_get_value (firstElementReader);
JsonReader *elementOfTagReader = json_reader_new (elementOfTag);
json_reader_read_member (elementOfTagReader, "one");
const gchar *oneValue = json_reader_get_string_value (elementOfTagReader);
// (abbr.)`

Comment: @hellodear: To get `JsonNode` from `std::string str`: `JsonParser *parser = json_parser_new ();
json_parser_load_from_data (parser, str, -1, NULL);
JsonNode *node = json_parser_get_root (parser);`